# Having trouble getting phpunit-selenium2 to click a button

Tags: selenium, phpunit

Here is the html for the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-hover-success"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add</button>
```

Here is the XPath path according to the chrome extension:

```
/body[@class='wide']/div[@class='container']/div[@id='main']/div[@class='container']/div[@class='content']/div[@class='users form']/form[@id='UserAddForm']/div[@class='button-control-row']/button[@class='btn btn-hover-success']
```

I have tried to target the button using `byXPath` and `byCssSelector` (and `byLinkText`, but it's not actually a link) without success.  This is the closest I have come:

```
    // Attempt to add a bogus user
    $netidInput = $this->byId('UserNetid');
    $netidInput->value('bogus01');
    $submitLink = $this->byCssSelector('button');
    $this->assertEquals('Add', $submitLink->text());
    $this->click();
    $this->assertContains('Users', $this->title());
```

The `assertEquals` successfully matches the 'Add' which is the button text but it can't click it.  I get the following error:

```
[root@#### View]# phpunit UsersViewTest.php 
PHPUnit 3.7.18 by Sebastian Bergmann.

E

Time: 5 seconds, Memory: 5.75Mb

There was 1 error:

1) UsersViewTest::testMyTest
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: '[JavaScript Error: "can't access dead object" {file: "file:///tmp/anonymous8204548738502860021webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/synthetic-mouse.js" line: 7462}]' when calling method: [wdIMouse::click]
Build info: version: '2.43.0', revision: '597b76b', time: '2014-09-09 20:52:14'
System info: host: '####', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.6.0_24'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

/var/www/html/formsdev/app/Plugin/BaseApp/Test/Case/View/UsersViewTest.php:25
/var/www/html/formsdev/app/Plugin/BaseApp/Test/Case/View/UsersViewTest.php:25

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 2, Errors: 1.
```

This is running against the Xvfb headless browser on RHEL 6.4.  Please let me know if I left out any relevant information.  Thanks for any suggestions you may have to offer!

Edit: adding another attempt with a different error that may trigger something for someone.

```
    $submitLink = $this->byXPath("//button[contains(text(),'Add')]");
    $this->assertEquals('Add', $submitLink->text());
    $this->click("//button[contains(text(),'Add')]");
```

This results in the error:

`There was 1 error:
1) UsersViewTest::testMyTest
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I was calling click incorrectly.  Instead of $this->click(), I needed to use $submitLink->click() and it works fine for either the XPath or CssSelector means of targetting it.

`// Attempt to add a bogus user
        $netidInput = $this->byId('UserNetid');
        $netidInput->value('bogus01');
        $submitLink = $this->byCssSelector('button');
        //$submitLink = $this->byXPath("//button[contains(text(),'Add')]");
        $this->assertEquals('Add', $submitLink->text());
        $submitLink->click();
        $this->assertContains('Users', $this->title());`

Cheers!